# how to make transition style apply to :before content

Tags: css, transition

html:

```
<div id='test'><span></span></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test:hover span:before{content:'I want this to make the div expand in ease'}
#test, #test span:before, #test span{-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;-o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;transition: all 0.2s ease-in}
```

I'm wondering if this can be achieved my CSS only: when mouseover `#test`, some text should be added into `span`, and the outer div should be expanded smoothly in ease.
The above HTML+CSS doesn't work, the `DIV` would expand immediately.

Comment: @DRD Look at the green button on this page [link](http://fbnychoir.org/index.php/chengyuan) please, I manage to get it work.. but not exactly as I want. I want the green button to expand with the text inside it together.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your transitions aren't working is because there is nothing to transition in this scenario.

Computed values don't work for CSS transitions, as a transition needs both an ***initial*** and a ***destination*** state.  So something like

```
#test span:before { 
   content: ''; 
   max-height: 0; 
   max-width: 0; 
   overflow: hidden;
   display: inline-block; }
#test:hover span:before { 
   content: 'I want this to make the div expand in ease';
   max-height: 500px;
   max-width: 500px;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

**will work** as the max height provides both an initial and destination value.  That is what becomes animated in this scenario, not the simple adding of content as the CSS is agnostic of what content in present in the element – *despite what you might think from seeing the content attribute in use for pseudo elements.*

Comment: It seems this solution doesn't work. See this page:http://fbnychoir.org/index.php/users, the element in question is the green button in the middle of the page with an envelope on it.

Comment: That link you provided is behind a login challenge, that's not going to work.

Comment: Check the edit.  Make sure you're defining both the span and its content as some block-level element, such as `inline-block` or `block`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/m49tdabh/.  Note: I would recommend adding content in between `span` tags instead of using pseudo-elements.

HTML:

```
<div id='test'>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
}

#test span {
    display: table;
}

#test span:before {
    content: "Hidden message displayed on hover";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: width 0.3s linear;
}

#test:hover span:before {
    width: 100%;
    border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Your width is relative to the next parental non-static container.  It completely obviates any benefit you'd see from using `inline-block` when you set the `width: 100%`

Comment: The `width: 100%` declaration instructs the browser to stretch the `:before` content to the width of its `table span`.  Because tables are blocks that shrinkwrap their content, the `:before` gets widened just enough to fit its contents.  To change the `:before`'s `width`, the `display` should be set to a `block` or `inline-block`.  Take your pick.

Comment: That's a pretty big assumption that he's using a table ... where does it state that?  He states specifically that he's using a `div` in the question, in fact.

Comment: Look at my code.  The `span`'s `display` is set to a `table` via CSS to enable shrinkwrapping behavior.  The `display: table` declaration is pretty useful for all kinds of situations.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  This is an incredibly silly question, honestly.  There's really no right answer to it because the question itself seems wrong.

Comment: lol sorry for my English. But giving the content of the question, you know what I am trying to ask, so if it was you, how would you compose the question?